# Deserialization of Json doesnt validate

Tags: javascript, json, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm using JavaScript in my Template to make a table. I decided to exchange the Data via JSON. Requesting the information and building the table works, but the the serializer wont validate the JSON data sent back to the server.

I'm using Django REST Framework and JQuery.

My view

```
def get_CEMatrix(request, id):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        Cells = CellCE.objects.filter(project=id).order_by('id')
        serializer = CellCESerializer(Cells, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = CellCESerializer(data=data, many = True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
```

my JS

```
alert(JSON.stringify(myRows));
$.ajax({
    "type": "POST",
    "dataType": "json",
    "url": get_CEMatrix,
    "data": JSON.stringify(myRows),
    "success": function(result) {
        alert("success of message to server and result is: " + result);
    }
});
```

Serializer

```
class CellCESerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    row = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    val = serializers.ListField()

    class Meta:
        model = CellCE
        fields = ('row','val')
```

for the model

```
class CellCE(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='1')
    row = models.ForeignKey('Descriptor', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    val = ArrayField(ArrayField(models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)))
```

I've implemented a function to Display the exchanged JSON data within the Template. The Server Sends JSON like this:

```
[
{
"row":"THIS IS AMAZING",
"val":[[139,
144,147],[0,0,0]]
},
{
"row":"HOLY FUCKING MOLY",
"val":[[139,
144,147],[0,0,0]]
},
{
"row":"OMG",
"val":[[139,
144,147],[0,0,0]]
}
]
```

The JSON sent to the server looks like this.

```
[
{
},
{
"row":"THIS IS AMAZING",
"val":"139 144 147 "
},
{
"row":"HOLY FUCKING MOLY",
"val":"139 144 147 "
},
{
"row":"OMG",
"val":"139 144 147 "
}
]
```

**Does the serializer not work the way i think it does, or is the JSON format sent back simply not good enough.**

I am open for any suggestions.

In case required, the entire JS

```
// TABLE FUNCION
$(document).ready(function(){
        // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
        var table = document.createElement("table");

        // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.
        var tr = table.insertRow(-1);
        // TABLE HEADER
        for (var i = -1; i < descriptornamelist.length; i++) {
          var th = document.createElement("th");
          if (i==-1) {
            th.innerHTML = "Descriptors";
            tr.appendChild(th);
          }
          else {
            th.innerHTML = descriptornamelist[i];
            tr.appendChild(th);
          }
        }

        // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
        //First Load with 1 Complete set of Data
        $.getJSON( get_CEMatrix , function(result){
          $.each(result, function(index, field){
            tr = table.insertRow(-1);

            //First COL with Descriptornames
            var tabCell = tr.insertCell(0);
            tabCell.innerHTML = field["row"];

             //Other COLs with Values
            for (var i = 0; i < descriptoridlist.length; i++) {
              var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
              tabCell.contentEditable = true; //change to 1 vor actual values
              tabCell.innerHTML = field["val"][0][i]; //change to 1 vor actual values
            };

          });
        });

        // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
        var divContainer = document.getElementById("CETable");
        divContainer.innerHTML = "";
        divContainer.appendChild(table);
});


//BUTTON FOR JSON TO SERVER
$(".table_to_JSON").click(function(){
  var myRows = [];

  // Loop through grabbing everything
  var $rows = $("tbody tr").each(function(index) {
    $cells = $(this).find("td");


    myRows[index] = {};

        $cells.each(function(cellIndex) {
            // Set the header text
              if( cellIndex == 0) {
                  myRows[index]["row"] = $(this).text();
              }
              if( cellIndex > 0) {
                if(myRows[index]["val"] === undefined){
                    myRows[index]["val"] =("");
                }
                myRows[index]["val"] += $(this).text() + (" ");

              }
        });

    });


alert(JSON.stringify(myRows));
$.ajax({
    "type": "POST",
    "dataType": "json",
    "url": get_CEMatrix,
    "data": JSON.stringify(myRows),
    "success": function(result) {
        alert("success of message to server and result is: " + result);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Try setting content type: **contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"**

Comment: What is your expected output? Please add that tooo.

Comment: @Help i changed the ajax call to `"dataType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",` but nothing changed. 
@JerinPeterGeorge for now: i expect to see that the objects in the database change (which i can see via adminpanel) or that a new object is created. 
Couldnt reply sooner, sorry about that.

Comment: I managed to continue working and realised both, the JSONresponse and the way the serializer handels data didnt work the way i wanted. I posted the next problem i encountered in here [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50025472/pass-additional-content-to-serializer-to-edit-listfield-befor-saving)